# FastAPI and Vue in Separate Google Cloud Run Instances Cannot Negotiate CORS

Tags: javascript, python, vue.js, cors, fastapi

I have a FastAPI backend communicating with a Vue frontend deployed in separate projects. I cannot seem to get proper browser negotiation between the two outside of localhost deployments (they work fine when containerized and deployed on a single machine on localhost:.  I tried first using the Cloud Run generated URL as a baseURL, but that didn't work.  I've added almost as many origins as I can think, went ahead and set up all the load balancers and domains with https, and same problem.  Not sure if FastAPI is failing to reply with the correct header or if the Vue app is missing some config.  CORS needs to die and better resource control frameworks put in place.  Until the brains that be figure out something better, I guess this needs to work for modern browsers to play correctly.

#### Fast API snippet from main:

```py
app = FastAPI()



# Add CORS middleware for frontend
origins = [
    "http://localhost",
    "http://localhost:8080",
    "http://127.0.0.1",
    "http://127.0.0.1:8080",
    "https://api.domain.com", # cloud run backend
    "https://alpha.domain.com", # cloud run frontend
]


app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins=origins,
    allow_origin_regex='https?://.*', <-- SHOULDN'T THIS BE THE DUMB WORKAROUND?
    allow_credentials=True,
    allow_methods=["*"],
    allow_headers=["*"],
)
```

#### Vue main.js

```js
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
import { createApp } from "vue";
import axios from 'axios';

import App from './App.vue';
import router from './router';
import store from './store';

const app = createApp(App);

axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;

// axios.defaults.baseURL = "http://localhost:8000";  // the FastAPI backend
console.log("Defaulting to GCP location: https://api.domain.com/");
axios.defaults.baseURL = "https://api.domain.com/";

app.use(router);
app.use(store);
app.mount("#app");
```

#### Vue vue.config.js

```js
const { defineConfig } = require('@vue/cli-service')
module.exports = defineConfig({
  transpileDependencies: true
})
```

- I tried wildcards in the FastAPI CORS setup.
- Tried various baseURLs.
- Tried moving everything behind a load balancer and using the production domain.
- Tried adding a DevServer: ...allowedHosts wildcard in Vue

Again, this works if both the HTTP and the FastAPI servers are run from localhost on the same network. Does not work when deployed. Instead, I get this:

```bash
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://api.domain.com/ping. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing). Status code: 200.
```

Neither Axios GET or POST are working.

Comment: set up all the load balancers ? Then why do you need multiple domains ? Can't you split the path in your LB :?

Comment: They are deployed to separate projects and I don't want to share a load balancer across them.  The backend is deployed to something like secure-domain-backend and the frontend to public-domain-frontend.  I can change the subdomain DNS integration to both be alpha.domain/frontend and alpha.domain/api instead of api.domain/, but that would imply they are on the same maturation level which is wrong. Rather not.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix it temporarily by disallowing credentials by default and using hooks to inject credentials only when I explicitly wanted to send them to the backend.

I moved all my auth into a body token and just stopped using headers, rewrote my backend user system to not have any PII, instead using an identity vector embed and UUID generator to create silent userIds on the fly that are stable on the platform but meaningless outside of it.